# Is there any way to get raw data from .git folder?

Tags: git, github, gitweb, git-server

I was trying to make my own git server. Something similar to github. Its made using a vm instance in GCP. I would like to add the feature of directly viewing the text in the files as well as the folder structure.

But as per the current architecture, we are initializing a bare repo (just the .git folder without the working directory). Is there a way to get the raw files.

Comment: You can get them with `git show the-branch:file-path`. I bet you can do the same thing with other libraries like libgit2

Comment: Just tried and `git cat-file -p the-branch:the-file-path` also works